# Fat32 browsing tool

Tags: filesystems, fat32

Are there any open source libraries / tools that allow me to do browse and FAT32 formatted image file? I want to extract some files from the image. (Edit: Sorry, i forgot to say i want to do this on Windows 7)

Comment: I use HxD editor to open a disk image.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux (and maybe some other unix-based operating systems), you can mount a formatted image file using the `-o loop` option of the mount command:

```
mount -o loop /path/to/image_file mount_point
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say i want to do this on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our [CallbackDisk](http://www.eldos.com/cbdisk/) library to create a virtual disk in code. The sample included with CallbackDisk will let you point at the FAT image file and have a disk.

Answer (score 0):

IsoBuster does exactly that !

[www.isobuster.com](http://www.isobuster.com)